# Shell script to find number of vowels in script

Tags: ubuntu

This is the script:

```
clear
echo
read str
len=`expr length $str`
count=0
while [ $len -gt 0 ]
do
    ch=`echo $str | cut -c $len`
    case $ch in
        [(aeiouAEIOU)]
            count=`expr $count + 1`
            echo $ch
            ;;

    len=`expr $len - 1`
done
echo $count
```

Error:

```
prog6: line 12: syntax error: unexpected newline (expecting ")")
```

Comment: You got the brackets and the parentheses inverted; `[(aeiouAEIOU)]` should be `([aeiouAEIOU])`.    And, are you really giving us the ***entire*** script?  Because that `syntax error: unexpected newline (expecting ")")` error looks like it could be coming from the `[(aeiouAEIOU)]`, but it's only the 10th line of what you're showing us.

Comment: Check your script here: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

why not use :

```
grep -o [aeiouAEIOU] file | wc -l
```

and here is your code (modified):

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo
read str
len=$(expr length $str)
count=0
while [ $len -gt 0 ]
do
   ch=$(echo $str | cut -c $len)
   case $ch in
      [aeiouAEIOU] )
         count=$(($count + 1))
         echo $ch
      ;;
   esac
   len=$(( $len - 1 ))
done
echo $count
```

Comment: ... or `tr -dc '[aeiouAEIOU]' < file | wc -c`.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
filename=$1
echo "Number of words with vowels"
while read line; do
        echo $line
        less $1 | grep -E [aeiouAEIOU] | wc -w > print.txt
done < print.txt

Comment: This script will count number of words with vowels: #!/bin/bash
filename=$1
echo "Number of words with vowels"
while read line; do
        echo $line
        less $1 | grep -E [aeiouAEIOU] | wc -w > print.txt
done < print.txt

Comment: `grep -o -i [aeiou] file | wc -l`, using the `-i` flag will enable you to get rid of case sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

I think you could really use some reformatting to see indentation and so forth.  The only thing that jumps out at me is you have no `esac` statement to close your `case`.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -n0E 'say y/aeiou//' file
```

In Perl, translate (`y///`) function, returns the name of translations...

Answer (score 0):

This script will work to count the number of words with vowel.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
echo "Number of words with vowels"
while read line; do
        echo $line
        less $1 | grep -E [aeiouAEIOU] | wc -w > print.txt
done < print.txt
```

Comment: It would be better to single-quote the RE, because otherwise the shell will attempt to use it as a glob and might match on a single-character filename in the current directory (if you have `a` in the directory, your `[aeiouAEIOU]` will collapse to just `a`). Also, double-quote your variables where you use them, so `"$1"` and `"$line"`. Finally, you declare but don't use `filename`, but you do have this really strange `less $1 | grep [aeiouAEIOU]` which could be better written as `grep -i '[aeiuo]' "$filename"`

Answer (score -1):

```
echo -n "enter string : "
read str
v=$(echo $str | grep -o -i "[aeiou]" | wc -l)
echo $v
```